# How to change login screen size, Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, login

So I have been using linux mint for a little bit now. One thing that really bugs me is that the login screen size is always really small. I have used `xrandr --output VGA1 --primary 1600x900` to set to to the right size until the next reboot but is there a better way?